# How to validate( format 000.0) the textbox in WP7

Tags: validation, windows-phone-7, textbox, decimal

I want to check the number format as the user types in each number in the following format 
Three digits before decimal and one digit after point(if any)

The moment the user enters the 3 digits, Im trying to add decimal point. Is there any event which is fired when user enters a number?

The TextInput and TextInputStart events do not work as expected. When i try to enter 332 it shows as 233. The following function is called on the TextInputStart event.

```
private void TestFunction(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txtbox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
        string r = txtbox.Text;

        if(r.Contains('.'))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < r.Length; i++)
            {
                if (r.Substring(i, 1) == ".")
                {
                    txtbox.Text = r.Substring(0, i + 2);

                }
            }
        }

        if (r.Length == 2 && r[2] != '.')
        {
            r += ".";
            txtbox.Text = r;
        }

    }
```

While debuggin i noticed that, TextInputStart is fired and the text box has the previous string and not the last entered string.

Any way out? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used regular expressions to check 3 digits before decimal and one digit after decimal. The following function is called on the key up event of the textbox. Saves a lot of time and can avoid the unnecessary use of messagebox. If anybody is looking out for an answer, here is mine.

```
 private void ValidateValue(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string sInput, sPattern;

        TextBox txtbox = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
        sInput = txtbox.Text;

        sPattern = @"^([0-9]{0,3})?(\.([0-9]{1})?)?$";
        Regex reg = new Regex(sPattern);


        if (reg.IsMatch(sInput))
        {
            if (sInput != "" && (sInput[0] == '.' || sInput[0] == '0'))
            {
                txtbox.Text = "";
                return;
            }

            txtbox.Text = sInput;
        }
        else
        {
            txtbox.Text = sInput.Substring(0, sInput.Length - 1);
            txtbox.Select(txtbox.Text.Length, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use OnKeyDown event, measure length of text, and if it is 3, add the decimal. You can also check the actual entered value using Regular Expressions or just set InputScope property on the TextBox to only provide the numeric keyboard for that particular TextBox.

If you do decide to add a decimal point yourself, then you may want to look at [this page here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752349.aspx), that describes how you move the cursor to the end of the text:

```
tbPositionCursor.Select(tbPositionCursor.Text.Length, 0);
```

Here is how you might want to handle the OnKeyDown event:

```
private void TextBox1_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox t = sender as TextBox;;
        if (e.Key == ...
```

So you are not checking the Text property of a TextBox, but rather the Key property of the KeyEventArgs.

Comment: On debugging I see that. When i enter the first digit for example '3', then the keydown event is fired but the r has value "" instead of 3 and after the execution of the eventhandler the 3 is placed. So the handler is fired when i press the key, but before the textbox can take the value 3. The input scope is already set to numeric

Comment: I updated the answer, but KooKiz is correct, you are not checking in the right place.

Comment: yes i got the last character, but only the last character i entered. so if i have entered 356 , e.text gives me only 6. Any way to return 356?

Comment: Can you append it to the .Text property of the TextBox?

Comment: i used regular expressions to solve this. . Anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The TextInputStart event is triggered before the TextBox is updated, that's why it still contains the old text. Instead of reading txtbox.Text, use e.Text.

Comment: Bingo ! Thanks a lot :) yes i got the last character, but only the last character i entered. so if i have entered 356 , e.text gives me only 6. Any way to return 356?

Comment: `txtbox.Text + e.Text` for instance.

Comment: Now it works when i enter 263 the '.' is appended and the string becomes 233. and it set to the textbox, but the last character is again. so finally the digit becomes 3263. :O

Comment: Not sure, but you may be able to prevent that by setting e.Handled to true.

Comment: @KoolKiz setting e.Handle = true does not do the trick. I have now set  txtbox.Select(txtbox.Text.Length, 0); which sets the cursor to the end. so When i enter 356 it displays as 356.6, the last character gets printed after the point. :(

Comment: The TextInput is fired the moment we enter a character in the textbox right? But the event is not being fired :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this applies also to WP7, but as it looks like C# so I'll give it a try.
In .NET you also have a MaskedTextBox, where you could apply a Mask with 0.00 .
The benefit: Your user may only input numbers of the given format and you don't have to code anything.

Comment: Wish there was a Mask Property but alas no! :(